# SwiftUI storing transition as state

Tags: animation, swiftui, state, transition, swiftui-form

I am trying to implement my own transition between views, where clicking the "Back" button will animate the transition in one direction while clicking the "Next" transition will animate it in the other.

```
struct InputForm: View {
    ...
    @Binding var idx: Int 
    let nextTransition = AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), removal: .move(edge: .leading))
    let backTransition = AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .leading), removal: .move(edge: .trailing))
    @State var activeTransition = AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), removal: .move(edge: .leading))
    var body: some View {
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.activeTransition = self.nextTransition
                        self.idx -= self.idx == 0 ? 0 : 1
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Back")
                }.buttonStyle(CoreBasicButtonStyle(color: .mainGray))
                
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.activeTransition = self.nextTransition
                        self.idx += self.idx == 1 ? 0 : 1
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Next")
                }.buttonStyle(CoreBasicButtonStyle(color: .mainGray))
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut)
        .transition(activeTransition)
    }
}
```

For some reason, it is only using the initial transition and never changing. Can SwiftUI not detect state changes for `.transition`?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)